# Disable carbonKit translucent effect

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Carbon kit for my application. I am setting the background colour of the `carbonTabSwipeScrollView` but it is showing `translucent` effect so it is mixing with background colour and not showing the proper colour of it.

```
let items = ["item 1", "item 2"]
    let carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: items, delegate: self)
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self, andTargetView: self.targetView)

    //Set Colors//
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setIndicatorColor(UIColor.clear)
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setSelectedColor(UIColor.blue, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13))
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setNormalColor(UIColor.lightGray, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13))
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.isTranslucent = false
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonTabSwipeScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonTabSwipeScrollView.bounces = false
```

Any help will be appreciated since I have been stuck in this issue since last 2 days and tried all the possible ways but not succeeded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First check if it has any tint color property or not, If it has, then clear its tint color, and hope it will work.

E.g:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar?.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
navigationController?.navigationBar?.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: I have tried as you suggest but still not getting proper result. Please check edits to the question.

Comment: can you show me the screenshot what you are getting and how you want ??